# How can I get the color of a character from a given position in a text?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I basically want to check whether a character in a given position in a text is a certain color. For example

```
if(character.inAposition == blue){
   change characters color
}
```

that's how I initially change the text color

```
TextPointer start = position.GetPositionAtOffset(indexInRun);
TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(word.Length);
TextRange rangeText = new TextRange(start, end);
rangeText.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Blue);
```

where indexInRun is the starting index of any substring that matches "word"

Answer (score 1):

You cant check a character. you can check a Run element of the RichTextBox Inlines collection. But you have to check if it really is a Run or something else like a complete TextBlock, or Image, etc.

Comment: I just put some more code in there,if you can show me an example of how you would do it

Comment: TextRange is just a string basically, it doesnt even inherit from TextElement.
You can iterate throught the Inlines property and find the word you are looking for in the Run objects(if they really are Run objects).
You mark all locations for later so you can change their Foreground.
If it is found but it is part of a sentence, you can remove the sentence from that location, break it, assemble it again with your word separately so you can change its Foreground, then place it back in the same location.